# Finding values in triple bracket question (algebra)

Tags: quadratics

How would I find the valued of $p$ and $q$ in the equation:

$$(x+p)(x+q)(x+5)= x^3+8x^²-3x-90$$

Any answers are well appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$(x+p)(x+q)(x+5)=x^3+x^2(p+q+5)+x(5p+5q+pq)+5pq$$
and compare the coefficients with $$x^3+8x^2-3x-90$$
so it must be $$8=p+q+5$$
$$-3=5p+5q+pq$$ and
$$5pq=-90$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I'm not quite sure from where this came from. Could you please explain further? (I'm only doing GCSE maths -- it's a grade 9 question, so I'm a little stuck)

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I understand now. Thanks again.

Comment: Good luck in solving!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be simpler if we start computing$$\frac{x^3+8x^2-3x-90}{x+5}$$ Now, when done, just use the quadratic formulae for the roots of the resulting polynomial.

Comment: How would you do the division in the first place?

Comment: @Adrian. Long division.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3+8x^2-3x-90 = x^3+5x^2+3x^2 -3x-90$$ $$ = x^2(x+5)+3(x^2-x-30)$$

$$ = x^2(x+5)+3(x-6)(x+5)$$
$$ = (x+5)(x^2+3x-18)$$
$$ = (x+5)(x+6)(x-3)$$

so $p= 6$ and $q=-3$